# Spring boot cassandra integration @EnableCassandraRepositories not generating implementation for Cassandra Repository

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-cassandra

I am trying to integrate cassandra with Spring boot using spring-data-cassandra.

Application.java

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    } 
}
```

CassandraConfiguration.java

```
package conf;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.CassandraClusterFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.java.AbstractCassandraConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.BasicCassandraMappingContext;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.CassandraMappingContext;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.config.EnableCassandraRepositories;


@Configuration
@EnableCassandraRepositories("dao")
public class CassandraConfiguration extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Override
    public CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster() {
        CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster = new CassandraClusterFactoryBean();
        cluster.setContactPoints("localhost");
        cluster.setPort(9042);
        return cluster;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getKeyspaceName() {
        return "mykeyspace";
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public CassandraMappingContext cassandraMapping() throws  ClassNotFoundException {
         return new BasicCassandraMappingContext();
    }

}
```

UserDao.java

```
package dao;

import hello.User;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.CassandraRepository;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.Query;

public interface UserDao extends CassandraRepository<User> {

    @Query("select * from users where fname = ?0")
    Iterable findByFname(String fname);
}
```

RestController.java

```
package hello;

import dao.UserDao; 
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


    @RestController
    public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserDao userDao;


    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public Iterable<User> getInfo(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="Hello") String name, @RequestParam(value="lname", defaultValue="World") String lname) {
        return userDao.findByFname(name) ;//new User(counter.incrementAndGet(),name, lname);
    }
}
```

User.java

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.Column;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.PrimaryKey;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.Table;

@Table
public class User {

    @PrimaryKey
    private final long id;
    @Column
    private final String fname;
    @Column
    private final String lname;

    public User(long id, String fname, String lname) {
        this.id = id;
        this.fname = fname;
        this.lname = lname;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }

    public String getLname() {
        return lname;
    }

}
```

Behind the scene @EnableCassandraConfiguration should create an implementation for UserDao interface. but seems like it is not doing so for some reason. Logs are not that useful to tell specific mistake i am making here. Still for help i am posting it here.

```
2015-02-11 12:10:58.424  INFO 7828 --- [           main] hello.Application                        : Starting Application on HOTCPC9941 with PID 7828 (C:\Users\prashant.tiwari\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DemoApp\target\classes started by prashant.tiwari in C:\Users\prashant.tiwari\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DemoApp)
2015-02-11 12:10:58.459  INFO 7828 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@4f5737ca: startup date [Wed Feb 11 12:10:58 GMT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-02-11 12:10:59.141  INFO 7828 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'beanNameViewResolver': replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]]
2015-02-11 12:10:59.865  INFO 7828 --- [           main] .t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory : Server initialized with port: 8080
2015-02-11 12:11:00.035  INFO 7828 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2015-02-11 12:11:00.036  INFO 7828 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.57
2015-02-11 12:11:00.127  INFO 7828 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2015-02-11 12:11:00.128  INFO 7828 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1672 ms
2015-02-11 12:11:00.555  INFO 7828 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2015-02-11 12:11:00.557  INFO 7828 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2015-02-11 12:11:00.682  WARN 7828 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: dao.UserDao hello.UserController.userDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [dao.UserDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1186)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:706)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
    at hello.Application.main(Application.java:12)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: dao.UserDao hello.UserController.userDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [dao.UserDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:298)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [dao.UserDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:862)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:494)
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems that your Dao class doesn't get registered into the context. I'd say it is missing an appropriate annotation like @Repository.

Additionally your `Application` class is living in the `hello` package and without any further configuration is only scanning for components below it. That is why it is not finding the `CassandraConfiguration` (living in `conf`). And this is then also not scanning the `dao` package.

Comment: Initially i thought since i have mentioned the base package in @EnableCassandraRepositories("dao") so it'll treat all the classes under that package a bean. but then i also have tried putting @Repository on UserDao class but still it is not happy.

Comment: No, it is just the annotation which will say which base package to scan for repositories. Since it is not working: can you post an update on the stack trace.

Comment: Issue remains the same "No qualifying bean of type [dao.UserDao]" which means that there isn't any bean registered in your context.

Comment: But mentioning @Repository on the UserDao class should register it as a bean. I am just trying to figure out what am i missing..

Comment: Just one additional question. I saw that your domain class is in the hello package whereas the dao class is in dao. Where does actually your CassandraConfiguration lives as well as how does your Class with the main method look like?

Comment: Hi, my Application class resides in hello package that has main method. CassandraConfiguration class resides in conf package. i will update these classes as well in the code to make things clear

Comment: Thanks, That helped. though still i am have problem in bean creation but problem is different. I think the original question is answered.

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the same problem for auto wiring the class which uses `cassandra` support, try adding:

`@EnableCassandraRepositories(basePackages="package path where where is ur bean")`