# Spring-Boot, Spring-Data-Cassandra: Autowire CassandraRepository, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: spring, cassandra, spring-boot, spring-data-cassandra

first question so far. Have trouble to Autowire CassandraRepository. I have a multiple databases project. I want to use Postgres, Mongo and Cassandra. I got Mongo working, but Cassandra is a pain. I followed the Cassandra Spring Repository Guide [Link (6. Repository)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.create-instances) [Link 2 (5. Repository)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/1.0.0.M1/reference/htmlsingle/#cassandra.repositories), this guide isn't completed by Spring Guys, its just mentioned it's same as mongo but thats not true. I did the same as for mongo and stumbled about this error: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28452047/spring-boot-cassandra-integration-enablecassandrarepositories-not-generating-im) with No qualifying Bean found to Autowire.

Found some google dev group mentioned the problem and solved it with some extra CassandraConfiguration Class. And now the Bean should be created, but i get a new Error, a better one i think.

```
   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraAdminOperations]: Factory method 'cassandraTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/cassandra/core/Cancellable
```

But at this time google didn't know the answer, spring boot is quite new... Have somebody tried to Autowire a CassandraRepository to an exisiting Spring-Boot Project? Could you help me?

Found a Solution:

1. Remove @Repository
2. Remove Versions in POM.XML, these Version are given by official website, but conflicting each other

Here are all my files:

Repository:

```
package com.kage.bigdata.bida.repository.cassandra;

import com.kage.bigdata.bida.model.QuestionEntity;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.TypedIdCassandraRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

/**
 *
 * @author bl4ckbird
 */

@Repository
public interface QCassandraRepository extends TypedIdCassandraRepository<QuestionEntity, Long>{

    public List<QuestionEntity> findAll();
}
```

Entity:

```
package com.kage.bigdata.bida.model;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.PrimaryKey;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.Table;

/**
 *
 * @author bl4ckbird
 */
   @Table
public class QuestionEntity {



    @PrimaryKey
    private long id;
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String question;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
                "Question[id=%s, Question='%s']",
                id, question);
    }

}
```

Service:

```
package com.kage.bigdata.bida.service.impl;

import com.kage.bigdata.bida.model.Question;
import com.kage.bigdata.bida.model.QuestionEntity;
import com.kage.bigdata.bida.repository.cassandra.QCassandraRepository;
import com.kage.bigdata.bida.repository.QuestionRepository;

import com.kage.bigdata.bida.service.QuestionService;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

/**
 *
 * @author bl4ckbird
 */

@Service
public class QuestionServiceImpl implements QuestionService{

    @Autowired
    QuestionRepository questionRepository;

    @Autowired
    QCassandraRepository cassandraRepository;

    public QuestionServiceImpl(){};

    @Override
    public void test() {
        Question q = new Question();
        q.setQuestion("Frage");

        questionRepository.save(q);

        System.out.println(questionRepository.findAll().get(0));

        QuestionEntity q2 = new QuestionEntity();
        q2.setQuestion("Frage2");

        cassandraRepository.save(q2);

        System.out.println(cassandraRepository.findAll().get(0));
    }

}
```

Config:

```
package com.kage.bigdata.bida.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.SchemaAction;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.java.AbstractCassandraConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.MappingCassandraConverter;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraOperations;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.BasicCassandraMappingContext;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.config.EnableCassandraRepositories;

/**
 *
 * @author bl4ckbird
 */
@Configuration
@EnableCassandraRepositories("com.kage.bigdata.bida.repository.cassandra")
public class CassandraConfig extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration{


    private static final String KEYSPACE_NAME = "Test_Cluster";
    private static final String CONTACT_POINTS = "127.0.0.1";
    private static final int PORT = 9042;
    private static final int MAX_POOL_CONNECTION = 50;

    @Override
    protected String getKeyspaceName() {

        return KEYSPACE_NAME;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getContactPoints() {
        return CONTACT_POINTS;
    }

    @Override
    protected int getPort() {
        return PORT;
    }

         @Override
        public SchemaAction getSchemaAction() {
            return SchemaAction.RECREATE_DROP_UNUSED;
        }

    @Bean
    public CassandraOperations operations() throws Exception {

        return new CassandraTemplate(session().getObject(), new MappingCassandraConverter(new BasicCassandraMappingContext()));
    } 

}
```

POM.XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.kage.bigdata</groupId>
    <artifactId>bida</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-cassandra</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Application:

```
package com.kage.bigdata.bida;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

/**
 *
 * @author bl4ckbird
 */
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable { 
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class); 
        app.run(); 
    } 
}
```

last but not least, Stacktrace:

```
Scanning for projects...

------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building bida 1.0-SNAPSHOT
------------------------------------------------------------------------

--- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) @ bida ---

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.2.3.RELEASE)

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/kage/bigdata/bida/config/CassandraConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraAdminOperations]: Factory method 'cassandraTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/cassandra/core/Cancellable
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.spriegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 52 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.cassandra.core.Cancellable
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 63 common frames omitted

ngframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at com.kage.bigdata.bida.Application.main(Application.java:30)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.kage.bigdata.bida.service.QuestionService com.kage.bigdata.bida.controller.QuestionController.questionService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'questionServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.kage.bigdata.bida.repository.cassandra.QCassandraRepository com.kage.bigdata.bida.service.impl.QuestionServiceImpl.cassandraRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'QCassandraRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cassandraTemplate' while setting bean property 'cassandraTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/kage/bigdata/bida/config/CassandraConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraAdminOperations]: Factory method 'cassandraTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/cassandra/core/Cancellable
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'questionServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.kage.bigdata.bida.repository.cassandra.QCassandraRepository com.kage.bigdata.bida.service.impl.QuestionServiceImpl.cassandraRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'QCassandraRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cassandraTemplate' while setting bean property 'cassandraTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/kage/bigdata/bida/config/CassandraConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraAdminOperations]: Factory method 'cassandraTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/cassandra/core/Cancellable
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.kage.bigdata.bida.repository.cassandra.QCassandraRepository com.kage.bigdata.bida.service.impl.QuestionServiceImpl.cassandraRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'QCassandraRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cassandraTemplate' while setting bean property 'cassandraTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/kage/bigdata/bida/config/CassandraConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraAdminOperations]: Factory method 'cassandraTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/cassandra/core/Cancellable
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'QCassandraRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cassandraTemplate' while setting bean property 'cassandraTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/kage/bigdata/bida/config/CassandraConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraAdminOperations]: Factory method 'cassandraTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/cassandra/core/Cancellable
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/kage/bigdata/bida/config/CassandraConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraAdminOperations]: Factory method 'cassandraTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/cassandra/core/Cancellable
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraAdminOperations]: Factory method 'cassandraTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/cassandra/core/Cancellable
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/cassandra/core/Cancellable
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.java.AbstractCassandraConfiguration.cassandraTemplate(AbstractCassandraConfiguration.java:85)
    at com.kage.bigdata.bida.config.CassandraConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ed9225d9.CGLIB$cassandraTemplate$9(<generated>)
    at com.kage.bigdata.bida.config.CassandraConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ed9225d9$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$28d9812.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309)
    at com.kage.bigdata.bida.config.CassandraConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ed9225d9.cassandraTemplate(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.cassandra.core.Cancellable
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 63 more
```

Comment: `Canceable` is defined in the `spring-cql:1.2.0` dependency which is a dependency of  `spring-data-cassandra`.
Try to execute a `mvn dependency:tree` and check which versions of `spring-cql` are resolved.

Comment: Found a solution, minutes ago. Just let maven decide which version it use.

Comment: You seems to have some conflicting dependency. When you remove the version from cassandra maven pick the version defined in a pom `dependenciesManagement` (surely the spring boot bom)

Comment: Thank you :) thats what i also found by 3 additional hours :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for your help in comments here is my solution:

Found a Solution:

```
Remove @Repository
Remove Versions in POM.XML, these Version are given by official website, but conflicting each other
```

Comment: No need to remove @Repository. Just removing version on spring-data-cassandra does the Job.

Comment: I'm just curious, how did you find that removing version will work. What was your clue?

Comment: The Cancelable Conflict how a class cloudn't be found. Its an internal Error so i guessed that in some refactoring phase they have removed that class. So i just deleted the version attributes and error was gone, thanks to maven in this point